# CodeIgniter 3, AJAX issue

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

Here we are talking about PHP CodeIgniter application with AJAX Calls and Sessions.

Hello to all!

I made some searchs on the web before posting this.

Configuration :

- Database stored sessions with encrypted cookie
- CodeIgniter 3.1.10
- jQuery 3.1.1
- PHP 5.6 or 7.x (same issue)
- Localhost : no problems with sessions or anything
- OVH mutualise server (shared) : SOMETIMES it looses session, it's not the same time, I think it's server-side configuration but I would like to know if some of you have also faced this problem??

The issue is that the AJAX call does not complete in case of session lost with an error like :

[JS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoKj6.png)

In fact, invalid JSON.

On phpinfo() for server-side le lifetime of cookie is 0, I think OVH Shared Server SOMETIMES renew sessions but it's not a fixed time.

For "normal" navigation (controller / method that load view), the check is OK, if session is lost, the application redirect user to login page.

*I'm working on a dedicated server, with a good configuration, this problem will be solved when the server will be OK (Migration and rework with CodeIgniter 4 with NodeJS services) but I'm curious about this issue...*

```
// Working for navigation
private function isLogged() {
    if (!$this->session->userdata('connected')) { 
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

For AJAX calls, it's.... hum... I tried some tricks to "handle" this issue, like this for AJAX calls :

```
// Not working on AJAX calls
private function ajaxIsLogged() {
    if (!$this->session->userdata('connected')) { 
        echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Session lost']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of AJAX calling

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
        },
        success: function (res) {
            // In my case when the issue occurs, ISSUE is HERE
            // Trying to parse non-valid JSON
            // But I don't understand why server would echo something
            // The function isAjaxLogged would normally do the trick
            var result = JSON.parse(res);

            if (result.error) {
                console.log(result.error);

                // Here we can redirect to login page if ajaxIsLogged() was working
            }

            if (result.success) {
                // Do things
            }
        }, error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

I've tried many things without JSON.parse but error still occurs (not exactly the same without JSON.parse but error always occurs BEFORE my control functions, enjoy asynchronous :))

Thanks for reading this, if any of you face this issue??
I'm looking far with some headaches for CI / Sessions / Ajax and sometimes the solution is just a little thing.

To summarize :

- Is there a way to cheat with sessions on shared / mutualise server with CI ?
- Is there a way to do a "proper trick" with AJAX requests when session is lost ?

Comment: try this to your isLogged function

    private function isLogged() 
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('connected')) 
        {
            
            if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
            {
                echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Session lost']);
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('user/login');
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Hello, ah didn't think of is_ajax_request for codeigniter. I will try this and see what happens,

Comment: The fact is the controller called in "url" is AJAX ONLY, so it won't be called for loading view or other things.

Comment: check this CI user guide
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::is_ajax_request

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Controller:

```
function ajaxIsLogged() {
    if (!$this->session->userdata('connected')) { 
        echo json_encode(['error' => false, 'message' => 'Session lost']);exit();
    }else{
        echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Session exists']);exit();
    }
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("div#divLoading").addClass('show');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("div#divLoading").removeClass('show');
        },
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }, error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer I will test this and see. But why you change type of ajax request (POST > GET), is there any link? Like I said, solutions are sometimes the little things you didn't think of lol.

Comment: It's very weird, because sometimes this condition : !$this->session->userdata('connected') is filled but the session data still here... So it won't do the trick everytime!